# Кривой скроллинг к элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток.

Задача: сделать аккордеон с функционалом, как на данном сайте - https://smylhub.com/. Почему при нажатиях на `<a>` скролл происходит не в правильное место (оно всегда разное)? Пытался использовать плагины - результат тот же.

HTML:

```
<pre>
  <ul class="accordeon_list">
    <li class="accordeon_item active" id="ac_itm_1">
      <a href="#" class="accordeon_trigger" id="ac_btn_1">click1</a>
      <span class="accordeon_inner">content</span>
    </li>
    <li class="accordeon_item" id="ac_itm_2">
      <a href="#" class="accordeon_trigger" id="ac_btn_2">click2</a>
      <span class="accordeon_inner">content</span>
    </li>
    <li class="accordeon_item" id="ac_itm_3">
      <a href="#" class="accordeon_trigger" id="ac_btn_3">click2</a>
      <span class="accordeon_inner">content</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</pre>
```

JS:

```
$(".accordeon_trigger").click(function (){
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).closest(".accordeon_item").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: @Crantisz вот код самого аккордеона:
    $('.accordeon_trigger').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
    item = $this.closest('.accordeon_item'),
    list = $this.closest('.accordeon_list'),
    items = list.find('.accordeon_item'),
    content = item.find('.accordeon_inner'),
    otherContent = list.find('.accordeon_inner');
    if (!item.hasClass('active')) {
    otherContent.stop(true).slideUp(400);
    content.stop(true).slideDown(400);
    items.removeClass('active');
    item.addClass('active');}});

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос. Нажмите "править"

Comment: Впринципе я уже ответил, только будет 400 мс длина задержки, а не 1000.

Answer (score 1):

**Для начала запретите переход по якорю**, добавив `return false` в конец обработчика события:

```
$(".accordeon_trigger").click(function (){
  ...
  return false;
});
```

**Второе, вы написали не весь код, и я могу только догадываться.** Как я понимаю, вы пытаетесь сразу настроить скролл на нужную позицию:

```
scrollTop: $(this).closest(".accordeon_item").offset().top
```

Перед этим вы назначили какую-то анимацию с блоками, какой-то блок скрывается, какой-то появляется, и почему-то решили, что `offset()` вернет вам **не текущие координаты**, а предскажет какие-то координаты из будущего.

Но дело в том, что фактически никаких изменений еще не произошло, и где будет `offset().top` после того как анимация блоков завершится **не известно**.

**Решение**

1) Вам нужно либо подождать, пока изменения придут в силу:

```
$(".accordeon_trigger").click(function (){
  setTimeout(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).closest(".accordeon_item").offset().top
      }, 2000);
  }), 1000) //1000 - длительность анимации с блоками
});
```

(`setTimeout`, не `delay`!)

2) Либо вычесть высоту скрываемого блока и добавить высоту появляемого блока